# Journey builder cross object data

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

We have a custom object "Coupon" in Sales Cloud. This object has Contact lookup field and 'coupon code' text field. When Coupon record is assigned to a contact, s/he will become a campaign member (depends on the coupon code, contact will be added to different campaigns).
I am setting up the journey builder in Marketing cloud to send out emails to contacts with coupon code.
In order to get Coupon Code field value, I use Coupon custom object as a journey entry source. 
However, I also would like to update the campaign member status after email is sent. If I want to do so, I should use Salesforce campaign as a data entry source, and I cannot have coupon code field value as a merge field on email.

Could someone give me suggestions, please? Thank you.

Comment: Hello @HRJ, If you are using Campaign as entry source, did you try to add coupon code field from "entry data" option, I hope contact fields should be visible there or you can synchronize Coupon object in Contact builder and add those to attributes or groups which will enable you to select the Coupon code from JB.

Comment: Thank you @EazyE, I will try to connect  objects in Contact builder!